# Compiler generating error when using C# required keyword

Tags: c#, .net

I have the most recent visual studio (17.3.1) and I am trying to use the new `required` keyword on properties of my record. `<LangVersion>` is set to `preview` in my project file to get this functionality.

The compiler is throwing 3 errors when I use the `required` keyword

```
CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RequiredMemberAttribute..ctor'
CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerFeatureRequiredAttribute..ctor'
CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SetsRequiredMembersAttribute..ctor'
```

I understand this is preview functionality and not officially supported, but I was hoping someone else may have run into this and found a workaround so I can check out this feature.

Comment: What framework version are you targeting?

Comment: Install preview version of VS (and .NET 7 SDK) or use dotnet build.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am targeting dotnet 6.0. Other features of C# 11 work such as raw literals.

Comment: I will try the 17.4 preview version of VS and target net 7

Comment: Yes, given that the attribute *does* exist in .NET 7 (preview 7 onwards IIRC) that may well be necessary for the feature.

Comment: So the left question is: We cannot use the required attribute with .netstandard2.0 as it is not a compiler-only feature? Will there be an additional nuget to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing .NET 7.0 SDK fixed the issue.

Comment: How can you use "required" in a multi-targeting environment?

Comment: @MichaelBrunner , I described the solution in my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/75995697/547639

Answer (score 3):

You need to install .NET 7 SDK or above, BUT if you are working with multi-targeting environment, for example targeting both .NET 7 and NetStandard2.1, then you can just add those attributes in your csproj:

```cs
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

/// <summary>
/// Indicates that compiler support for a particular feature is required for the location where this attribute is applied.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class CompilerFeatureRequiredAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CompilerFeatureRequiredAttribute(string featureName)
    {
        FeatureName = featureName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the compiler feature.
    /// </summary>
    public string FeatureName { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If true, the compiler can choose to allow access to the location where this attribute is applied if it does not understand <see cref="FeatureName"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsOptional { get; init; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="FeatureName"/> used for the ref structs C# feature.
    /// </summary>
    public const string RefStructs = nameof(RefStructs);

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="FeatureName"/> used for the required members C# feature.
    /// </summary>
    public const string RequiredMembers = nameof(RequiredMembers);
}
```

```cs
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

/// <summary>Specifies that a type has required members or that a member is required.</summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
#if SYSTEM_PRIVATE_CORELIB
    public
#else
internal
#endif
    sealed class RequiredMemberAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

```cs
namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

/// <summary>
/// Specifies that this constructor sets all required members for the current type, and callers
/// do not need to set any required members themselves.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Constructor, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
#if SYSTEM_PRIVATE_CORELIB
    public
#else
internal
#endif
    sealed class SetsRequiredMembersAttribute : Attribute
{ }
```

Comment: In order to compile the CompilerFeatureRequiredAttribute you also need to add `internal static class IsExternalInit {}`. [See here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/IsExternalInit.cs)